# Open URL in Flex error

Tags: apache-flex, browser, flash-builder

I am trying to make a button action open a browser window to a particular `URL` and I think I've almost got it but there is a weird problem going on. The code below opens a new browser window but adds the `URL` to the end of the `URL` from the parent window. See below:

```
protected function launchPrinter_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var url:String = dataGrid2.selectedItem.ip_address;
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            navigateToURL(urlRequest);
        }
```

Here is the parent URL:
`http://???.???.???.???/IT%20Tools-debug/Main.html`

Here is the URL from the newly created browser window:
`http://???.???.???.???/IT%20Tools-debug/15.155.205.134`

How do I open a new browser window with just the `url` variable being the address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url:String = "http://"+dataGrid2.selectedItem.ip_address;
```